# OpenCv Fastest way to make Mat Image from 1 D Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, image, opencv, mat

I am new in `OpenCV`. I have a `unsigned char` array of size `5038848` to create a `Image of 1944*2592` what is the fastest way to making the image from that 1 D array.
I have done this using `Nested Loop` but I think it take lot of time to create a single frame. 
So can anyone please tell the other solution which is faster than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an empty `Mat` and set the data to be your array.

```cpp
unsigned char* array = ...
img = cv::Mat(1944,2592, CV_8U);
img.data = array;

cv::imshow('My image', img);
cv::waitKey()
```

A faster method would be to directly create the `Mat` with your data. This way, no data pointer is allocated when creating the object. It might also be safer as you're not manipulating internal data pointers directly.

```
img = cv::Mat(1944, 2592, CV_8U, array);
```

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala Even if your array is 1D, it is going to be interpreted as 2D by the `Mat` object.

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala Take a look at [this Mat constructor](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/c0cc246f-7c2a-e2c9-7b98-f2a98beef077.htm) that takes an `IntPtr` as argument to create the image with existing data. There is acutally the same kind of constructor in C++ that you could use instead of the method I showed.